# Routing ensuring all areas are touched

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, routing, area

I'm making a web application with leaflet and OSM. It's all going well, but now I need a little help.

I'm searching for a good routing engine, that's capable of creating the most probably taken route based on "checkarea":

I've many points logged every N minutes, and they are not really precise, but their offset should be 400m, average of 200m. I need to know what route has been taken.

I'll explain better:

[image: Example]

I've this start A and finish B point. The black line it's like a street map, blue dots are points I calculated and blue circle are areas where it should route. The yellow path it's what the engine should calculate.

I've starting modifying Pyroutelib2, but maybe I'm just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Search for travelling salesperson problem. Multiple libraries available

Comment: Do you know sequence of those blue points? If sequence is determined, then there's nothing to do with Travelling salesman problem.

Comment: I know the sequence of bluepoints. Better yet, I know the timestamps. My problem is that blue points are not precise, so I cannot set them as waypoints, as for example, point near but not in a motorway will lead the routing to exit from the motorway. I have already searched the salesman problem , before posting this, but it's not my case. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: For related questions see http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q="map+matching"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should look for is called '[Map Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching)'. I've opened sourced [my idea](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/digitalizing-gpx-points-or-how-to-track-vehicles-with-graphhopper/) based on [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/) very recently [here](https://github.com/karussell/map-matching) so it is still in a VERY early shape, please give feedback via providing data or creating issues etc.

Comment: Nice idea and nice site! About your suggested improvements, I've two ideas: 1)Overlapping points: when there are points that are near, divide in subtracks: before the overlapping point, the loop, after the overlapping point. 2)Precision: See if the edges are of the same type: if there where highway on point-1 and point+1, and point is near but not touching the motorway, move it a little. Tell me if it's a good idea (may I write you PMs?) Bye!

Comment: You can just create an issue, not sure if I can follow here :)